# How do I retrieve the UIScrollView programatically? (iOS 5 Storyboard)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, storyboard

I just added a `UIScrollView` on top of a `UIView` (using Storyboard). How do I retrieve the `UIScrollView` programatically?

Comment: Just link to it with an IBOutlet?

Comment: I just did it programatically a few hours ago. However, I reverted my code and forget how I did it. I tried it again - honestly - but I didn't get it to work. So, I need help - I'm sure someone knows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;`

Then link it in with IB

Comment: How do you link it using Storyboard?

Comment: In IB right click on the ViewController, find your outlet in the list, drag from the little circle over to the ScrollView. They will be linked.

Comment: I guess I figured out to do this in Storyboard: Open the Storyboard and code at the same file. Then, simply control-drag the object to the code. Everything is inserted automatically.